# Finding domain and range without equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, real-numbers

We are given that $f(x)$ has domain $x \geq -4$ and $f(x) < -1$. All numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now we want to find the domain of $3f(x+1)+4$. My solution is $x+1 \geq -4$ so new domain is $x \geq -5$ and $3f(x)+4 < -1$ so $f(x) < -\frac{5}{3}$.

Have I made any missteps here? Specifically, am I correct in treating the domain and range as having nothing to do with each other so their calculations are kept separate?

Comment: What is $y$? I don't see it defined anywhere

Comment: @Andrei thanks for the catch. I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is correct. For the second part:$$f(x)<-1\\3f(x)<-3\\3f(x)+4<-3+4$$